# Automatically run tests when publishing from github to an azure website?

Tags: azure, github, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

If I bind my azure website to TFS, I can configure the build to run the unit tests in the project. However, I can't seem to find a similar option when publishing from github. Am I missing something?

My site publishes fine, but, based on the information I'm seeing in the log, I'm pretty sure the tests aren't being executed. In my unwritten book, Continuous Integration demands that all tests are executed and passing before the build can be pushed out into production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/azuregit/thread/1743558f-1366-4748-b87e-576da9b19678

Guess I wasn't searching for the right thing initially. Hoping there's an update to this soon.